# Does web scraping pull contents from a database (php)

Tags: php, web-scraping

I don't know anything about web scraping so before I spend time toying with it I want to see if it will even work for what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to return all the pertinent information about a part using the part number (quantity, cost, etc.) I assume the contents of the website is stored in a database so my question is does web scraping have the ability to get to the contents on the database?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This questions show a lack of basic understanding about how the Internet works

Comment: Please rewrite your question so have a better understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: You get what ever the website displays, assuming there is no client side code generation. So maybe, but irrelevant. Like painting a car and asking if it runs with '87 or '93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web scraping means reading a website and extracting information from the pages of interest.

That most (interesting) websites use a database to do its work means that webscraping is indirectly reading a database.

Another approach to get data would be using a API to avoid the complication and inefficiency of parsing HTML and finding the information.  Not all websites provide an API interface.  Give specifics and someone might be able to tell you if and how to do it.

Comment: Should we be answering low quality questions like this?

Comment: @JohnConde:  I assume the question will be moved to a more suitable website (like superuser), so a useful answer can greet it.

Comment: I don't think there is a more suitable website for this question. It's just low quality, period.

Comment: @JohnConde:  The question which wants to be asked is "how to write a program to get the information I see on a website?"  At least I think that is what the OP means....

Comment: Which is *way* too broad for any website in the stack exchange network including this one. It should be closed.